# Dialog: how to change round border to square?

Tags: flutter, dialog

Dialog border: how to change round border to square?

```
showDialog(context, 
    builder: (context) {
       return Dialog(child: ...);
    }
);
```

The Dialog class does not have border attribute. Default is round border.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the content of the Dialog with a Container and setting the BoxDecoration with a square border.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0), 
      ),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.white, 
            width: 2.0, 
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0), 
        ),
        child: ..........,
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

[image: Example output]